# Why is my display making a high-pitched noise?

Tags: display

I have a Samsung SyncMaster 940BW monitor. Around 4 months ago (with a graphics board upgrade) I passed from using VGA to a DVI connection.

Around a month or so, I have been hearing strange, hi-pitched sounds coming from the back of the monitor (more or less where the power cable connects to the monitor) and also a very faint burning plastic odor coming from the back.

The sounds seemed to be more audible when the monitor was off (but still connected to power) and also seemed to be in sync with the power LED at front. It also took a long time to turn on from sleep, reaching as much as 10 minutes. As of yesterday it no longer shows any image, even the test pattern.

From the information I could gather online, it seems as though the monitor reached the end of its live and/or there are some bad capacitors, although this being the first time it happened I have no way to tell. Hence I ask:

- Has my monitor "died"?
- Why does it make the hi-pitched sound I mentioned earlier?
- Would it be feasible to repair by an end user?

Comment: "very faint burning plastic odor coming from the back" ruh ruh raggy - that's likely a VERY bad thing. And from my experience in fixing *one* monitor... I'd say its probably not worth the time investment. I've replaced every cap on that thing, and currently have backlight issues that may need a replacement transistor.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I had backlight issues with my monitor and applying solder on the MOSFET drivers pins solved the problem. Just like you, I replaced a few caps before that :(

Comment: Yeah, I need to check. Kinda tempted to try doing a ghetto LED mod instead ;p

Comment: I think you may have let the magic smoke escape. Once you do that, there's no way to get it back inside & make it work any more;)

Comment: "very faint burning plastic odor coming from the back" - I had that with a CRT monitor at work a long while ago. While trying to work out where the smell was coming from ... a few minutes later there was black smoke and flames ... please turn it off and replace it before you have a fire ...

Comment: An update. I managed to partially disassemble the monitor. I noticed some bulging capacitors (that also wobbled somewhat, as in, they weren't well fixed to the board), but nothing burned or otherwise remarkable, other than a lot of dust.

Comment: bulging = no magic smoke. It's gone already

Answer (score 4):

The sound is coming from the power supply of the monitor.

You say it is more audible when in stand-by and in-sync with the power LED. I have an LG monitor which does the same.

It's a power supply design issue. Most devices nowadays are using switched mode power supplies which adjust the switching frequency depending on the load (the power needed by your monitor). When in stand-by the switching frequency (which is above the human ear limit of 20 kHz) drops below this limit.

The "issue" is that this is the frequency of an electrical current and by no means you'd be able to hear it. So something must have become loose (probably the switching transformer's core or some pin of the power transistor that controls the transformer which would explain the overheating and the smell).

Power supplies of LCD monitors can be repaired/replaced if you have electronics knowledge. Most probably, there is a [dry joint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_contact) somewhere.

Just as a measure of safety, don't let the monitor plugged into mains even in stand-by for long times or when not using.

Comment: As I stated, it stopped giving any sort of image so it doesn't make sense to use it (I'm using a replacement monitor that gets the job done). Your explanation makes sense, but I would need to check the monitor's electronics. A quick note though, I never noticed any overheating, just a very faint smell (that if not for my sense of smell would most likely go unnoticed)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard are you sure it isn't giving image, or the backlight is off? The smell must be coming from something that overheats, something too small to cause a sensible heating of the entire monitor case.

Comment: -1 You wrote "The "issue" is that this is the frequency of an electrical current and by no means you'd be able to hear it. So something must have become loose "  <-- actually the noise of a current through electrical coils is something which some people can often hear - I can. It is called coil whine. And it is not from something loose. Now, it may be that his noise is caused by something else.. But you saying people can't hear these things and only if something is loose, isn't correct. If a component is made from ferrite it can help, but cheaper forms of iron can be an issue.

Comment: @barlop indeed, you're right. But in SMPS designs, coils are usually on ferrite cores and should be glued tightly in order to prevent any vibration.

Comment: @Cornelius is there an easy way to know if an ACDC adaptor is switch mode or linear mode?  I've heard whining ACDC adaptors.. I've seen old faashioned big Televisions whine.  Flat screen ones seem to be ok.  This morex power supply card from 2002-ish hummed like hell http://www.mitxpc.com/web/ps/morex/mx0608A.jpg     (though PicoPSU ones seem fine). Is the ACDC Adaptor to a monitor somehow completely distinct electronically, as higher power requirement and has to be switch mode? And the others mentioned are linear? And it's not just ACDC adaptors.. Big old fashioned non-flat screen TVs too.